# Azure Storage Account Lifecycle Management filter prefix for blobs in dynamically created sub-directories

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, lifecycle, azure-storage-account

So I have a quick question regarding filter prefixes related to lifecycle management for azure storage account V2.

So the scenario I'm faced with is that I have a blob directory/container which in turn contains sub directories created dynamically via a function that pushes/creates blobs depending on conditions, so the directories are created depending on that logic.

The problem I want to solve is that I want to delete the blobs after 7 days.

In the documentation for lifecycle management it says that I can set a filter prefix for which container I want to apply the "retention rule" for, so to speak.

So the question related to what I'm trying to do is the following:

When setting the filter prefix for a blob container to: "containerName/",
as it says to do in the documentation will it also look in the subfolders?

In the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-overview#the-blob-prefix-match-string-didnt-apply-the-policy-to-the-expected-blobs) it says:

> "A prefix match string like container1/ applies to all blobs in the
> container named container1."

Does that also include all the blobs in all the subfolders automatically. or do I have to specify each subfolder after the slash as it says further down in the same part of the documentation?

I would like to include all blobs in that first container regardless if they are in subfolders or not as the subfolders are created dynamically as mentioned before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does that also include all the blobs in all the subfolders
> automatically. or do I have to specify each subfolder after the slash
> as it says further down in the same part of the documentation?

Yes, when you set the prefix as container name, all blobs (including those in subfolders) will be considered thus you need not specify subfolders specifically.

You would specify subfolder in prefix only when you want to lifecycle management to manage blobs inside a specific subfolder.

Comment: Perfect! thank you for the quick response. :)

Comment: Gaurav, if I created a lifecycle being "contain" would that automatically apply to "container"?